# Change Jetty WebSocketListener thread name

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

How would I specify a `ThreadFactory` to change the Thread names that invoke the callbacks (`onWebSocketConnect` and `onWebSocketText`) of the `WebSocketListener`?

The thread name would be a fixed name that is known already before I create the Server object.

I tried the following which didn't work unfortunately.

```java
jettyServer = new Server(new NamedQueuedThreadPool("MyThreadNamePrefix");

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;

class NamedQueuedThreadPool extends QueuedThreadPool {
    private final String threadName;

    public NamedQueuedThreadPool(final String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        Thread t = super.newThread(runnable);
        t.setName(threadName);
        return t;
    }
}
```

I still see thread names like: `qtp1692017180-191` (which i guess stands for queued thread pool)

I am using `jetty-server-9.2.9`

**Edit:**
For me it doesnt care which thread executes a specific client request, I only want that all the threads have the same name which I can choose somewhere.

For example I would prefix the thread name of all threads with "Adapter/SomeInstanceId", this is than written into the logs and gives me a convenient way of filtering/grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ThreadPool`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool.html) in Jetty, and the java [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) that it uses are in ultimate controls the thread names, and they are only really relevant to the the thread pool itself.

Besides, the lifetime of a WebSocket means that many different threads can be active for that WebSocket.  So setting a name and expecting it to stick to a specific WebSocket endpoint instance is highly unlikely.

If the WebSocket goes idle long enough (think in terms of milliseconds), then the thread goes back in the pool for other resources on your Jetty server to utilize.

Once there is a need (say a WebSocket write or WebSocket endpoint has some content to read), then a new Thread is obtained from the ThreadPool to process this new activity.

Also the `ThreadPool` in Jetty can be used for many things, unrelated to processing of a specific `ServerConnector` endpoint, there is also cases where the Thread is needed to handle closure notifications of a WebSocket where the `ServerConnector` and endpoint no longer exist.  No adapter, no network anything, etc.

If you want filtering of your logs, don't do it via the Thread name, use a proper logging framework, like [`logback`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html), and setup some other sort of filtering on the logs themselves. (You can even [capture all logging events](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-slf4j-multiple-loggers.html) from all logging frameworks and route them to a single log file)

Some options:

- Use [MDC/NDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) properties.

  - Setup at WebApp initialization time, to include webapp details in the logging event.
  - Setup at [`ServerConnector.configure(Socket)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html#configure(java.net.Socket)) to include connection details in the logging event.
  - Setup during the Request handling via a custom MDC Filter to include request details (like request path, user-agent, client remote ip, user name, etc ...)
- [Centralized Logging from multiple webapps](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-logback-centralized.html), routed all to the Server side logging and then [Sifted](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) or with Custom `pattern` entries to indicate the details you need.
- Even some combination of the above to suit your needs.

In short, if your end goal is relating log events together, or log searching, or log sorting, or generally anything to do with logging, don't do it via Thread names (that's the wrong approach)

Comment: I understand that a socket is not bound to a single thread. I only want that ALL the threads in the pool have the same name which I can specify somewhere once. I dont understand why Jetty does not use the ThreadPool implementation that I provided in the ctor of the Server. (or does it internaly overwrite the name?? i dont know)

Comment: Updated answer to address your core concern (ie: thread name manipulation is the wrong approach)